# How to login bot via WTelegramClient

Tags: bots, telegram, tdlib, wtelegramclient

> This library allows you to connect to Telegram and control a user programmatically (or a bot, but Telegram.Bot is much easier for that).

I see WTelegramClient can control a bot, but I don't know how to login a bot. Please give me an exsample just like login user account.

I have used TDLib, but I also can't login a bot. If you know how to login bot via TDLib, please tell me, it's also helpful.Thanks!

ps:I want to login a bot, not user. And I know Telegram Bot Api, but I need use user and bot  together.

Answer (score 0):

make your Config callback answer to **"bot_token"**
and call `client.LoginBotIfNeeded()`

or simply `client.LoginBotIfNeeded(bot_token)` in latest version

Comment: Yes, I hvae saw this function later. Sorry, I'm thoughtless. Thanks!

Comment: @Wizou it keeps asking me for some more hash: `Enter api hash:`